# what do you connect to IN+ and IN- for ADC differential input configuration?

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, differential

I was trying to understand how to read analog inputs on a raspberry pi.  I found this video post and I think I understood how it works.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oW0mTwFck_c
This video uses a potentiometer and read its analog outputs through `MCP3004` microchip.

In this video, he says to use "1" for the `single / diff` control bit, and he didn't explain much about the differential input.  I was curious, and after some searches, I found that it was used to reduce noises when to read analog outputs.

Now, when I look at this diagram,
http://i.gyazo.com/f86370f39c199b4b8a4fe345b1486b09.png
I understand how to use CH1, 2, 3, 4 for single input type (you just connect analog sensor output to one of them), but for the differential, it says `IN+` or `IN-`, and this gets me really confused.

What do I need to connect for the + and -?

Can anybody explain what to do when you have a potentiometer to read just like the video example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, a differential ADC is used to measure the difference between two signals.

For a simple potentiometer, there isn't really two different signals to measure, so you're measuring the difference between the wiper and ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3uwZi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When working in single-ended mode the - input of the ADC is connected to ground internally for you, so you basically end up with the same circuit anyway.

Now, the fun comes when you have a more complex circuit.  If your potentiometer forms just part of a chain of resistances, and you need to know exactly the voltage across just the potentiometer, then the differential ADC comes in very handy:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnbgoI.png)</sup>

Now with the ADC you are measuring the difference just between the wiper and the lower point of the potentiometer.  The other resistors are then ignored by the ADC.

Any strange fluctuations in the voltages in that resistor network are also ignored, since the same fluctuations will be proportionally the same throughout - at both the wiper and at the lower side of the ADC, so they will not be sensed by the ADC.

Comment: you said _For a simple potentiometer, there isn't really two different signals to measure_ , so this means to be able to use differential input mode, your analog sensor should have 2 outputs(+/-)?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It can be ± outputs from a sensor, or, as in my second schematic, a single output from a sensor, and an offset voltage. You notice I have used the op-amp symbol for the ADC in the schematics - that's because that's effectively what the ADC is like - the two inputs of an op-amp.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the differential signals are used to reduce the noise picked up by the wires transferring the signal. The differential signal is usually transferred using a pair of twisted wires, such that if there is some EM noise is picked up by one of the wires, most likely it will be picked up by the second one as well, so the difference between them will remain the same. And since the actual signal is encoded by the difference between the two wires, it is remaining unchanged and thus immune to this type of noise. 
 So as said: 
1) If your input signal is differential, it should have it positive and negative channel. So you are connecting the positive one to the IN+ and the negative one to IN-. 
2) If you have a single ended input signal Vin, you just use a zero (ground) or some known reference voltage Vref for for the IN-, and your actual signal for IN+. In this case the output of the ADC will be proportional to (Vin - Vref).

Comment: yes, I think I understand how differential reduce noises, but my question was more like of asking "what is IN+/- for a potentiometer.  which wires?"  Or if analog sensors need to have 2 outputs for differential mode, can you show me an analog sensor that has 2 outputs?

Comment: Potentiometer has one variable signal and two fixed. So it is single ended, and the variable is connected to the in+. In- is going to ground or some fixed voltage.

Comment: ok so this potentionmeter in the video was a single ended sensor.  Can you name one typical differential sensor?  I want to know what it is like.